# clearRect not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have a number of different shapes inside canvas. I want to clear a particular canvas or blur it if user clicks on it

```
$("canvas").click(function(event) {

var id = event.target.id;
var c = document.getElementById(id)

var ctx = c.getContext("2D");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
});
```

It is fetching the right id but I don't know why it is not getting cleared.
canvases are like-

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas1" class="" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error comes from `getContext("2D")`. Change it to `getContext("2d")`.

You could also simplify your code to something like this:

```
$("canvas").click(function(event) {
    var ctx = $(this)[0].getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck for like an hour.